# whole or partial string - for search function

Tags: php, mysql

Example:

```
$test = 'My name is'
```

I would need to return records which contain: 'My name is' OR 'my' OR 'name' OR 'is'.

I'm pretty sure MySQL has some function or some regular expression for this type of task.

Answer (score 1):

you need to read more about [pattern matching in Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html)

for example

`SELECT * FROM`table`where title REGEXP "some regex pattern"`

for your case , it maybe some thing like this :

```
SELECT * FROM `table` where title REGEXP "(My|name|is)"
```

Comment: FULL TABLE SCAN , so no index usage

Comment: uhmmm thanks @BerndBuffen , but i think he had to mention some thing important like that .

Comment: i have wrote a answer with fulltext search. you can also weigth the results to get the best first

Answer (score 1):

You can also use FULLTEXT search in InnoDB like this:

```
SELECT * FROM search
WHERE MATCH(mytext) AGAINST('my name sample' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

**Note**

you must set **ft_min_word_len** in your my.cnf. default is set to 4

a description from FULLTEXT search is : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/fulltext-index-overview/

**create sample table**

```
CREATE TABLE `search` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `mytext` TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `ft_mytext` (`mytext`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**show all and search**

```
mysql> select * from search;
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
| id | mytext                                              |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
|  0 | Sample text includes My name is and much more text  |
|  1 | Only name in it                                     |
|  2 | now is includet sample                              |
|  3 | nothing of them in string                           |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM search
    -> WHERE MATCH(mytext) AGAINST('my name sample' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
| id | mytext                                              |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
|  0 | Sample text includes My name is and much more text  |
|  1 | Only name in it                                     |
|  2 | now is includet sample                              |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM search WHERE MATCH(mytext) AGAINST('sample nothing' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
| id | mytext                                              |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
|  3 | nothing of them in string                           |
|  0 | Sample text includes My name is and much more text  |
|  2 | now is includet sample                              |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: notice that in mysql you only can use full text search in myisam engines for mysql version < 5.6 , for versions greater than 5.6 innodb engine supports full text search

Answer (score 0):

Use query as follow:

```
select * from tbl_name where name like '%my%' OR name like '%name%' OR name like '%is%';
```

Comment: Example given was a constant. I need something, that would work if typed string would be like 'Checking news for tonight'.

Comment: You can construct the SQL dynamically.  But that is a separate topic.